# How to prove the significance of features in classification?

Tags: machine-learning, data-mining, dataset, feature-selection, feature-engineering

I have a binary classification problem. I have extracted 500 features from a set of 5000 samples using my domain knowledge. In other words, I have got **hand crafted features**.

> I wish to prove that these features actually are enough for performing classification and they make the 2 classes of samples separable. i.e. When the samples are represented with these features, there is exists a (reasonable) decision boundary.

Please advice on how I can prove this. 
Is there any statistically appropriate way of measuring the significance of the set of features as a whole (NOT the significance of individual features)?

EDIT: Suppose if I observe that different families of classifiers such as kNN, DT, NB, ANN, SVM etc. (with 10 fold cross validation) offer reasonable accuracy, can I conclude that the features are meaningful?

Comment: Is there some reason the obvious answer "asses a classifier using these features" isn't applicable?

Comment: //asses a classifier using these features// - could you point to some reference or literature for propoer way of doing this (of course, I did google ;))

Comment: Typically with some resampling procedure like bootstrap or cross-validation.

Answer (score 0):

**YES**

Here’s a question to ponder: if you had to make a prediction but did not have access to any features, what would you predict? For instance, if you had to predict the color of the card on the top of the deck but only got to look at the back, what would you predict?

There are multiple reasonable answers to that, particularly when you get into potential costs of missing the right answer (especially severe penalty for missing high might encourage you to guess low, for instance). However, I think a reasonable answer to the card question is to predict that black and red each have a probability of $0.5$, since a standard deck of cards is split even between red and black. You would do this for every card for which I show you the back.

If you collect additional information about the card, such as what the front looks like, you can start to get better predictions than guessing $0.5$ every time. If you can reliably make predictions that are more accurate than guessing $0.5$ every time, then it would seem that your features, taken as a group, are determinants of the outcome.

Getting a p-value or confidence interval is harder, but I believe this to be the right philosophy.

When you do an F-test of all the features in a linear model, for example, you are testing if including those features allows you to make better predictions of the conditional expected value than you would if you made the same prediction every time. The mechanics of how this is done have a justification, and that justification is different when you do a test of the significance of the features in a logistic regression, but the F-test is philosophically the same as the idea of seeing if including features allows you make better predictions than you could if you lacked them.